# Stop auto-scrolling on a split or cloned window in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-11

Using NetBeans version 11.3, when splitting or doing a clone of an opened document tab I can scroll to different position in each view while editing the same document, I can also type and change the document in these different positions, the problem is that if i'm doing an UNDO / REDO operation on one view , the second view automatically scrolls to the cursor's position of the first view, is there a way to disable that automatic scroll?

Comment: Same here. It is kind of annoying and it will be nice if someone figured out how to disable it.

Comment: NetBeans 12.3 still has this problem

Comment: Netbeans 21 still has this problem.